# How do I decrypt RSA keys from Windows Key Store?

Tags: encryption, rsa, dpapi

In this path: %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

Keys are stored there but I can't make use of them. When I open them in a HEX EDITOR, I can only see parts of it, the remaining parts seems to be encrypted via CryptoAPI. How do I decrypt it?

Note: This key in particular was not created by an application I developed. I did some research and it seems CryptoAPI uses DPAPI to protect them. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code at [this site](http://dpapick.com). They provide code to decrypt these certificates (which are used for EFS, among others). You do need the user password for Windows.

Comment: That site doesn't exist now. The associated code is here: https://bitbucket.org/jmichel/dpapick/src/default/